# Undefined index for product

Tags: magento2

Whats undefined index here in 'product'?

```
    ...
    $query = $this->request->getParam('q');   
    $q = $this->request; 
    $re =  array();
    $re = $q->getParams();  

    $re['filters'] = true;
    $re['q'] = $re['product'];
```

I get the error :

> Undefined index: product

Comment: what does this code even do? or what should it do?

Answer (score 5):

This means that the array `$re` does not contain the element with the key `product`.
It means you are calling the script from a page where you expect a get parameter called `product`but that is not there.

Additional comments:
This script looks funny (not funny Ha ha, funny oh!).

You are getting `q` parameter from GET, 
Then you are getting the full request, 
then initialize an array as empty, then immediately replace it with a list of all request params.
then in this line `$re['q'] = $re['product'];` you are overwriting the value of a parameter that exists (`GET[q]`) with `GET[product]`.
it does not make too much sense.